# Laravel 8 validate unique through columns and rows on create and update

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have got 3 columns in my table email_1, email_2, email_3. How to avoid duplicates between the rows while create and update?

For the update method, I can validate by columns like this:

```php
public function rules()
{
    /** OTHER VALIDATION RULES */

    'email_1' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    'unique:users,email_1,' . $this->id,
    ],
    'email_2' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    'unique:users,email_2,' . $this->id,
    ],
    'email_3' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    'unique:users,email_3,' . $this->id,
    ]
    /** OTHER VALIDATION RULES */
}
```

The problem is avoiding using the same email address on the three input fields of my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

The easiest way is to use the `different` validation rule. Something like this:

```
'email_1' => [
  'required',
  'email',
  'different:email_2'
  'different:email_3',
  'unique:users,email,' . $this->id,
],
'email_2' => [
  'required',
  'email',
  'different:email_1'
  'different:email_3',
  'unique:users,email_2,' . $this->id,
],
'email_3' => [
  'required',
  'email',
  'different:email_1'
  'different:email_2',
  'unique:users,email_3,' . $this->id,
],
```

### Method 2

I see you're validating within a `Request` class, which is great because you can make use of [After Hooks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests).

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $emails = [Request['email_1'], Request['email_2'], Request['email_3']];
    $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($emails) {
        if (count($emails) == count(array_unique($emails))) {
            // Add error to message bag.
            $validator->errors()->add('key', 'message');
        }
    });
}
```

The above example uses `array_unique()`, which will remove duplicates. Comparing length of original vs length of deduplicated one will show if duplicates are present.

Comment: I found the first method and saw your answer like at the same time. Method 2 seems also great, but it's really too much for the purpose of my application. Great Explained

Comment: Glad I could help 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `different` rule on **email_2** and **email_3** to ensure that all 3 values are different.

```php
 public function rules(){
            
             /** OTHER VALIDATION RULES */

             'email_1' => [
                 'required',
                 'email',
                 'unique:users,email,' . $this->id,
             ],
             'email_2' => [
                 'required',
                 'email',
                 'unique:users,email_2,' . $this->id,
                 'different:email_1',
             ],
             'email_3' => [
                 'required',
                 'email',
                 'unique:users,email_3,' . $this->id,
                 'different:email_2',
             ],    

           /** OTHER VALIDATION RULES */
        }
```